# Not able to retrieve repository team using application access_token

Tags: github, jwt, github-api

I am having issues accessing [GitHub List repository teams](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repository-teams) endpoint. When I do that using my personal access token everything is OK, however, if I try to access using the [application access token](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authenticating-with-github-apps) it results in an empty list. The token seems to be correct because it returns different resources (f.e. list of repositories or repository details) without any problems.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Does the application need some sort of special access rights for teams?

Thank you for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that for Application to access information about teams, it not only requires access to `- Repository permissions -> Administration` but as well `Organization permissions -> Members`. I am yet to find out whether there is some change in our organisation setup, which resulted in this failure, or whether there was a change in GitHub API

Comment: It was confirmed by GitHub, that they have recently fixed a bug, where Teams were provided to the application even the application did not specifically request the permissions for teams. Because of that our application started to fail and the correct way of fixing it is to grant the above peermissions